# How to print frontslash in C?

Tags: html, c, bash, cgi

Hi i'm having issues printing frontslash '/' on my html files, i need to collect data from a select input and send the values to my .cgi files but when i select a value like "/home" it prints "%2Fhome" how i can fix this? thank for ur answers..

```
Shell: <select name=shell>
    <option value="/bin/bash">/bin/bash</option>
    <option value="/bin/sh">/bin/sh</option>
    <option value="/usr/bin/csh">/usr/bin/csh</option>
    <option value="/bin/false">/bin/false</option>
    </select><br>
```

Comment: HTTP POST data is URL-encoded, which replaces special characters with % followed by a hex code. You should use a CGI library to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below read and print to terminal the passed file. Tested with your text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fd;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Open requested file
    fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    // Check file opened
    if ( fd == NULL )
    {
        // Couldn't open file
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Step through the file until EOF occurs
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    // Close file
    fclose(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile it with command: `gcc -o test test.c -Wall -std=c99`

Then call it as: `./test test.txt`